# Setting public void method to JTextField

Tags: java, methods, jtextfield

When program is executed void type not allowed here errors shows
[Program error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXIBr.png)

resultField.setText((ai.inOrder(ai.root))); **causes the error above**

I want the content in the array to be passed through Class BST. java then returned in Result TextField.

How do I fix this?

Bellow is the code

**MAIN**

```
package p3gui;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class P3GUI extends JFrame {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Binary Search Tree Sort");// Title

    private final JButton evaluate;
    private final JLabel textfieldLabel;
    private final JTextField entryField;
    private final JLabel resutfieldlabel;
    private final JLabel radioLabel1;
    private final JLabel radioLabel2;
    private final JTextField resultField;
    private final JRadioButton ascending;
    private final JRadioButton descending;
    private final JRadioButton integer;
    private final JRadioButton fraction;
    private final ButtonGroup radioButtons = new ButtonGroup();
    private final ButtonGroup radioButtons2 = new ButtonGroup();
    private final JOptionPane popup = new JOptionPane();

    P3GUI() 
    {
        f.setSize(425, 375);
        f.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers  
        f.setVisible(true);//making the frame visible  //window size
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        radioLabel2 = new JLabel(" Numeric Type ");
        f.add(radioLabel2);
        radioLabel2.setBounds(225, 275, 100, 15);

        integer = new JRadioButton(" Integer ");
        radioButtons.add(integer);
        f.add(integer);
        integer.setBounds(225, 295, 160, 15);

        fraction = new JRadioButton(" Fraction ");
        radioButtons.add(fraction);
        f.add(fraction);
        fraction.setBounds(225, 315, 160, 15);

        radioLabel1 = new JLabel(" Sorted Order ");
        f.add(radioLabel1);
        radioLabel1.setBounds(10, 275, 100, 15);


        ascending = new JRadioButton(" Ascending ");
        radioButtons2.add(ascending);
        f.add(ascending);
        ascending.setBounds(10, 295, 160, 15);

        descending = new JRadioButton(" Descending ");
        radioButtons2.add(descending);
        f.add(descending);
        descending.setBounds(10, 315, 160, 15);

        textfieldLabel = new JLabel(" Original List ");
        f.add(textfieldLabel);
        textfieldLabel.setBounds(42, 10, 160, 25);

        entryField = new JTextField("");
        //entryField.addActionListener(this);//ActionListener
        f.add(entryField);
        entryField.setBounds(118, 10, 245, 25);


        evaluate = new JButton(" Perform Sort ");
        f.add(evaluate);
        evaluate.setBounds(137, 180, 130, 30);


        resutfieldlabel = new JLabel(" Sorted List ");
        f.add(resutfieldlabel);
        resutfieldlabel.setBounds(52, 100, 100, 25);

        resultField = new JTextField("");
        //resultField.addActionListener(this);//ActionListener
        resultField.setEditable(false);
        f.add(resultField);
        resultField.setBounds(125, 100, 220, 25);

        evaluate.addActionListener(new getItListener());

    }//END of P3GUI

    class getItListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text;

            /*text = entryField.getText().trim(). replaceAll(" ","");
           String textArray[] = text.split(" ");*/
            text = getAmtValue();
            String textArray[] = text.split(" ");

            if (ascending.isSelected() && integer.isSelected()) { 

                BST ai = new BST(new Integer(textArray[0]));
                for (int i = 1; i < textArray.length; i++) {
                    ai.insert(ai.root, new Integer(textArray[i]));
                }
                resultField.setText((ai.inOrder(ai.root)));


            } else if (descending.isSelected() && integer.isSelected()) { 
                //Do Something
            } else if (ascending.isSelected() && fraction.isSelected()) { 
                // Do Something
            } else if (descending.isSelected() && fraction.isSelected()) { 
              // Do Something
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(popup, "Please enter valid 
           amount.");
            }
        }
    }

    public String getAmtValue() {
        try {
            return (entryField.getText().trim().replaceAll(" ", ""));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("This is not a number");
            eraseTextField();
            return "";
        }
    }

    //clears text field
    public void eraseTextField() {
        entryField.setText("");
        entryField.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P3GUI p3GUI;
        p3GUI = new P3GUI();

    }
}
```

package p3gui;

```
class Node {

    public Object element;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;

    // CONSTRUCTORS 
    public Node(Object theElement) {
        this(theElement, null, null);
    }

    public Node(Object theElement, Node lLink, Node rLink) {
        element = theElement;
        this.left = lLink;
        this.right = rLink;
    }
}
```

**BST.Java**

```
public class BST {

    public Node root;

    public BST(Object x) { // ONLY CONSTRUCTOR//
        root = new Node(x);
    }


    public Node insert(Node node, Integer x) {
        if (node == null) {
            return node = new Node(x);
        }
        if (x < (Integer) node.element) {
            node.left = insert(node.left, x);
        } else {
            node.right = insert(node.right, x);
        }
        return node;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @param node
     */
    public void inOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            inOrder(node.left);

            inOrder(node.right);
        }
    }


    /**
     *
     * @param node
     */
    public void descOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            descOrder(node.right);

            descOrder(node.left);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see how to create a [mcve]. This has a lot of not relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your inOrder method is a void method.
You can't set the text value of your field with a void method, because a void method doesn't return anything.

If the inOrder method were to return a String, it would be fine.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. How would I make that return a String?

Comment: I think you want to keep that method a void, and create another method to get data you want to show. Which data would you like to put in the textfield? You are talking about an array in the BTS class, but I can't find an array there?

Comment: I want to put the array in descending or ascending order depending on what the user selects on the radio button. Example user input 25364 if they selected the descending it would display 65432 in the result JTextField.

Comment: I don't know where to begin. There are multiple things wrong with your code. First of all, your getAmtValue() method removes any Space characters, but later you split on space characters, which will result in an array with only one value. Your for loop will never work because the length of your array is already 1, so it will never go into it. And I can go on. I would suggest to debug through your code and work it out one by one...